# using loop for only if statement and then print else statement

Tags: c++, loops, if-statement

> Check whether if the entered character is consonant or vowel?

I almost got the result but I just need `else` statement to be out of loop.
Is it possible to use `else` out of loop? Here I tried adding `{}` but didn't help me. How do I do so
?
I have solved this program in many ways but I want to clear my concepts of `if` and loop.

```
#include <iostream>
    
using namespace std;

int main(){
    char x ;
    char vowel[10] ={'a','e','i','o','u','A','E','I','O','U'};
    cout<<"Enter ";
    cin>>x ;
    for(int i = 0 ; i<10 ; i++)
    {
        {    
            if(x ==vowel[i])
            {
                cout<<"This is a vowel";
            }
        }   
        else
        {
            cout<<"This is a consonant";
        }   
    }
    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: BTW, it's "consonant", not "constant".

Comment: get used to apply indentation, it helps you in first place to avoid errors and see code correctly. If structure is too long to read it's  too complex (and you may mistakes) and may require breaking up into functional blocks, If not, try use  comments to mark loop end, long if/else blocks ends, etc.

Comment: remove braces  { } around `if` statement. `else` must follow the closing brace (}) of the corresponding `if` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop `for( statement expression; action ) body`  loop is just a while loop

```
{
   statement;
   while ( expression )
   {
     body

label_for_continue:
     action;
   }
}
```

So you can see that everything  declared inside  will have its life ending outside of `for`. You can use `break` to stop loop prematurely and `continue` to jump back to beginning of loop after performing `action` ( equals to `goto label_for_continue`), this makes it a little more versatile than `while` where `continue` jumps directly to "beginning".

Any or all parts may be omitted or used in ways allowed by syntax of language, resulting in use of external counter, a "forever" loop `for(;;)` or pre-increment loop `for(int i = MAX; i-->0;)`. A special case of for loop use is [range-based loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for).

What you need to do is to use some external variable to  mark your current state. Let it be `false` by default, because if your loop exits normally, it means that you didn't found a match. If you found match, you would "short-circuit" loop by `break` after setting flag to true:

```
bool is_vowel = false;
for (int i = 0 ; i<10 ; i++) {
    if (x == vowel[i]) {
        is_vowel = true;
        break; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also write:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    std::cout << "\nEnter a character: ";

    if (char c{}; std::cin >> c)
        std::cout << c << " is a " << (((0x208222 >> (c & 0x1f)) & 1) ? "vowel" : "consonant") << '\n';
   return 0;
}
```

That is more compact.

---

This shows how wonderful problems can be solved in C++. But, it needs a lot of explanations. First, How to check, if a character is a vowel.

If we use the ASCII code to encode letters, then we will see the following:

[image: Ascci Code for Letters]

We see that the ASCII code for uppercase and lowercase letters just differ in the lower 5 bits. So, if we mask the ASCII code with 0x1F, so `char c{'a'}; unsigned int x{c & 0x1F}`, we will get values between 1 and 26. So, we can calculte a 5 bit value for each letter. If we now mark all vowels with a 1, we can build a binary number, consisting of 32bits (an unsigned int) and set a bit at each position, where the vowel is true. We then get something like

```
Bit position
3322 2222 2222 1111 1111 1100 0000 0000  
1098 7654 3210 9876 5432 1098 7654 3210  
Position with vowels:
0000 0000 0010 0000 1000 0010 0010 0010
```

This numer can be converted to 0x208222. And if we now want to find out, if a letter (regardless whether upper- or lowercase) is a vowel, then we mask out the not necessary bits from the chararcter ( C & 1F ) and shift the binary number to the right as much positions, as the resulting letter code has. If then the bit is set at the LSB position, then we have a vowel. This know how is decades old.

Aha. Not so easy, but will work for ASCII coded letters.

By the way, it would also work for other selections of characters.

the result is :

```
auto isVowel = [](char c) { return (0x208222 >> (c & 0x1f)) & 1; };
```

Cool . . .

Answer (score 2):

You can set a 'flag':

```
#include <iostream> 

int main() {
    char x ;

    const char vowel[10] ={'a','e','i','o','u','A','E','I','O','U'};

    std::cout<<"Enter ";
    std::cin>>x;

    bool is_vowel = false;

    for (int i = 0 ; i<10 ; i++) {
        if (x == vowel[i]) {
            is_vowel = true;
            break; // break not necessary but faster
        }
    }

    if (is_vowel)
        std::cout<<"This is a vowel";
    else
        std::cout<<"This is a constant";

    return 0 ;
}
```

If you don't mind moving the logic to a function
A function lets us `return` at any point in the function:

```
const char vowel[10] ={'a','e','i','o','u','A','E','I','O','U'};

def is_vowel(char c) {
    for (int i = 0 ; i<10 ; i++) {
        if (x == vowel[i]) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

def main() {

    char x ;

    std::cout<<"Enter ";
    std::cin>>x;


    if (is_vowel(x))
        std::cout<<"This is a vowel";
    else
        std::cout<<"This is a constant";

    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: thanks @darkspine. I wasn't knowing about flags. It was really helpful. I was trying to solve this from the past half an hour.

Comment: in the first example that you gave.

``` if (x == vowel[i]) {
            is_vowel = true;
            break; // break not necessary but faster
        }
```
I want to use the value of i for which bool became true outside of loop.
without calling a new function
 How do I do that??

Comment: So instead of returning `true` or `false` you could return `i` and `-1`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code won't compile because you added {} and seperated `else` from `if`.
Try to change this loop like this:

```
bool isVowel = false;

for(int i = 0 ; i<10 ; i++) {  
    if(x == vowel[i]) {
        isVowel = true;
        break;
    }
}

if(isVowel)
    cout << "This is a vowel";
else
    cout<< "This is a consonant";
```

Comment: this won't work. because if i give input 'e' . It'll give output as "This is constant." As a[0] was a . And it'll break program from here.Giving the wrong output

Comment: indeed, this doesn't work.

Comment: @Hercules yeah thanks, I have edited

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to do it by using a boolean.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  char x;
  char vowel[10] = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U'};
  bool isVowel = false;

  cout << "Enter ";
  cin >> x;

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
  {
    if (vowel[i] == x)
    {
      isVowel=true;
      break;
    }
  }

  isVowel ? cout << "This is a vowel" : cout << "This is a consonant";

  return 0;
}
```

You can also do it with a range based for loop so you don't have to worry about the array size.

```
for (char &a : vowel)
  {
    if (a == x)
    {
      isVowel=true;
      break;
    }
  }
```