# removing vowels from c++ string

Tags: c++, string, io

```
char arr[5000];
ifstream is("test.txt"); 
is.get(arr,5000);
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
cout << arr << endl;
char anar[5000];
while (arr[i] != '\0')
{
    if (arr[i] == 'i' || arr[i] == 'a' || arr[i] == 'e' ||
    arr[i] == 'o' || arr[i] == 'u')
        {
        ++i; 
        }
    else anar[j] = arr[i]; ++j; ++i; 
}++j; anar[j] = '\0';
cout << anar << endl; 
ofstream os("test.txt"); 
os.write(anar, sizeof(char)); 
cout << "written successfully" << endl;
```

should read the data from a file and delete the vowels from this string. After deleting vowels, it should assign the result to another string. But vowels seem strange characters and the writen file is only one character long.

Comment: This would be much simpler with [std::copy_if`.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How big do you think `sizeof(char)` is? So how many characters is this going to write?

```
os.write(anar, sizeof(char));
```

You actually have `j` characters in your array, so this works

```
os.write(anar, j);
```

But since you have a null terminated character array even simpler would be

```
os << anar;
```

Some other errors, look at this loop

```
while (arr[i] != '\0')
{
    if (arr[i] == 'i' || arr[i] == 'a' || arr[i] == 'e' ||
    arr[i] == 'o' || arr[i] == 'u')
        {
        ++i; 
        }
    else anar[j] = arr[i]; ++j; ++i; 
}++j; anar[j] = '\0';
```

It looks like you are missing `{}` around the else part of the if statement. You also have an extra `++j` after the while loop for some reason. Here's how it should look (I think)

```
while (arr[i] != '\0')
{
    if (arr[i] == 'i' || arr[i] == 'a' || arr[i] == 'e' ||
    arr[i] == 'o' || arr[i] == 'u')
    {
        ++i; 
    }
    else
    {
        anar[j] = arr[i];
        ++j;
        ++i;
    } 
}
anar[j] = '\0';
```

Notice how much easier these problems are to spot if you get into the habit of consistently indenting your code. You should do this.

BTW there are no C++ strings in your code, only character arrays.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Writing file is okay. But why vowels are changing when i remove the vowels source text= "Split the binary I/O program from into two: one program that converts an ordinary text file into binary and one program that reads binary and converts it to text." output=" SplÌ thÌbÌÌy I/O prÌrÌ frÌ ÌtÌtwÌ ÌÌprÌrÌ thÌ cÌvÌts Ì ÌdÌÌy tÌt fÌÌÌtÌbÌÌy Ìd ÌÌprÌrÌ thÌ rÌds bÌÌy Ìd cÌvÌts Ì tÌtÌt.Ì"

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. How can the vowels change when you are deleting them?

Comment: Thanks. After paranthesis it worked. Last ++j to terminate character arrays. I will consider your advice. How can I do if I use strings instead of character arrays.

Comment: `#include <string> std::string arr;`. It would take too long to explain how to use C++ strings here. They're not too different from arrays but you should read about then in your C++ text book.

Answer (score 0):

A very good answer has been given by *john* already. So, the problem is solved.

I would like to recommend to you to learn a little bit about C++ and all the existing libraries. Especially the C++ - algorithms library is very powerful.

Look at the below program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>


int main() {

    // Open files and check, if they could be opened
    if (std::ifstream is("withvowels.txt"); is)
        if (std::ofstream os("withoutvowels.txt"); os)

            // Copy file and remove vowels
            std::copy_if(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(is), {}, std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>(os), [](const char c) { return !((0x208222 >> (c & 0x1f)) & 1); });
}
```

So, in essence, we have just 3 statements: 2 times `if` with initializer. And then one `copy_if` with a lambda for vowel detection.

If you want to know more about the lambda and vowel detection you can read in one of my other posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65593449/using-loop-for-only-if-statement-and-then-print-else-statement/65594665#65594665).

---

**EDIT**

Op asked, how to read the file into a `std::string`. I added a new piece of code, where I first read the complete file into a `std::string` and then `erase`/`remove` the vowels. The result is shown on `std::cout`

Please see:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>

int main() {
    // Open file and check, if it could be opened
    if (std::ifstream is("r:\\withvowels.txt"); is) {

        // Read the complete file into string variable s
        std::string s(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(is), {});

        // Remove all vowels from string
        s.erase(std::remove_if(s.begin(), s.end(), [](const char c) { return ((0x208222 >> (c & 0x1f)) & 1); }), s.end());

        // Show result
        std::cout << s;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am not experienced. of course you can write many different and effective ways. but I want to get logic

Comment: how can I read many words to a string if it contains whitespaces and new lines. if I want to do same thing "string str" instead of "char arr[size]"

Comment: @dilem-ma-vi: Please see the edited and updated answer.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I like this implementation much